# SQLAlchemy Adjacency List Queries

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to create a simple Flask application that models network devices and their membership to arbitrarily-named domains (if it's relevant, the tool will be used to define MPLS LSP meshes between the devices. I'm using sqlite for dev and production will be postgres). The relationships should go as follows:

- domain to subdomain: one to many
- domain to device: one to many
- subdomain to domain: one to one
- device to domain: one to one

Here is my model:

```
class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'device'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    hostname = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    mgmt_ip = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    snmp_comm = db.Column(db.String(255))
    domain_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('domain.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Hostname %r>' % (self.hostname)

class Domain(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'domain'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('domain.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    children = db.relationship("Domain")
    devices = db.relationship("Device")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Domain %r>' % (self.name)
```

How can I structure my SQLAlchemy query to start at the device itself and recurse *up* the tree to get to the given root Domain (with no parents) in order to generate a list of devices in each domain up the tree? As an example:

```
from app import db
from app.models import Device, Domain

db.create_all()

d1 = Domain(name='mandatory')
db.session.add(d1)
db.session.commit()
d2 = Domain(name='metro_A', parent_id=1)
db.session.add(d2)
db.session.commit()
d3 = Domain(name='metro_B', parent_id=1)
db.session.add(d3)
db.session.commit()

dev1 = Device(hostname='switch_1', mgmt_ip='1.1.1.1', snmp_comm='public', domain_id=1)
dev2 = Device(hostname='switch_2', mgmt_ip='2.2.2.2', snmp_comm='public', domain_id=1)
dev3 = Device(hostname='switch_3', mgmt_ip='3.3.3.3', snmp_comm='public', domain_id=2)
dev4 = Device(hostname='switch_4', mgmt_ip='4.4.4.4', snmp_comm='public', domain_id=2)
dev5 = Device(hostname='switch_5', mgmt_ip='5.5.5.5', snmp_comm='public', domain_id=3)
dev6 = Device(hostname='switch_6', mgmt_ip='6.6.6.6', snmp_comm='public', domain_id=3)

db.session.add_all([dev1, dev2, dev3, dev4, dev5, dev6])

db.session.commit()
```

The goal here is, given `switch_1` as an input, how do I get a list of other devices in its domain, *plus* the devices in its parent domain (and, if it applies in the real world, recurse until I reach its root domain)?

Comment: Some reading: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html and http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/adjacency_list/adjacency_list.html

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the links, but I had read over them already before I came to SO and was left thoroughly confused. I get why the question was closed though.

Comment: About if you need a single table for both: your current model is good as it is.

Comment: Thanks - I'll attempt to hit the docs a little harder and see how far I get.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I'm unfortunately still stuck, but I've rephrased the question (assuming I should do that rather than asking a new one).

Comment: That's a lot more to the point, so voted for reopen. To get you going, traversing tree structures in SQL can be achieved using a recursive CTE. Try to make a query for parents first, then it should be easy to join devices belonging to the found domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traversing tree structures can be done using a recursive Common Table Expression in SQL. Given your goal to fetch the domain of a device and its possible parent domains, and then all the devices in those domains, you could start by creating a [CTE](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.cte) for fetching the domains:

```
domain_alias = db.aliased(Domain)

# Domain of switch_1 has no parents, so for demonstration switch_6
# is a better target.
initial = db.session.query(Domain.id, Domain.parent_id).\
    join(Device).\
    filter_by(hostname='switch_6').\
    cte(recursive=True)

child = db.aliased(initial)

domain_query = initial.union(
    db.session.query(domain_alias.id, domain_alias.parent_id).
        join(child, child.c.parent_id == domain_alias.id))
```

And then just fetch the devices that are in the found domains:

```
db.session.query(Device).\
    join(domain_query, domain_query.c.id == Device.domain_id).\
    all()
```

Comment: thank you very much for the pointer. I'll give this a try. I wrote an actual recursive function to handle this as a stop gap - are there limitations to the recursive CTE method (ie it won't work with certain db backends)? While my recursive function works, I still have to flatten/munge the returned results to get what I'm actually after, and it no doubt doesn't seem ideal for the database (multiple queries when one will do etc).

Comment: I think at least Postgresql, SQLite, Oracle, SQL Server, and the latest MySQL support recursive CTE.

Comment: that's great then, as production will be postgres. thank you very much again!!! if this nets a cleaner result than my function i'll come back and mark as accepted.

Comment: Just wanted to report back that your query worked swimmingly. I still don't understand what it's doing, but I'll do my best to try to figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the Postgresql docs explain how a recursive CTE works nicely: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html.